# How can I remove the padding of an image while still padding all other elements?

Tags: html, css, sass, jekyll

I am trying to make a listing website. I am using the Jekyll [Moonwalk](https://github.com/abhinavs/moonwalk) theme as a base and heavily adapting it to my needs.

This is my first website project, so I am figuring it out as I go. I want to remove `padding` from images in the projects listing, while still padding everything else.

Right now it looks like this:

[image: Placeholder]

I want it to look closer to the BetterDiscord themes page, with the image in the top of the box without padding, while still padding the other elements:

[image: BetterDiscord Theme box]

- I have attempted to add `negative padding` to the images
- I have added `!important` in the sccs to:

```
img {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  padding: 0em !important;
}
```

As I said, I have no HTML/CSS experience prior to this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will most likely need to remove the padding of the box which all of the elements are housed inside:

[image: Image showing box padding]

Which will cause your content to flow to the edges of the box:
[Image showing elements against box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wi9rF.png)

And then add margins to the other elements inside the box
[Image showing new margins on inner elements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loF5d.png)

Please ignore my quick attempt at recreating the box from your pictures, it is just for illustration purposes :)

Additionally you can remove padding for all images using

```
img { padding:0px; }
```

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a helpful answer. I am now running into an issue that the text is not being effected by margins anymore. I want to move this text down but it is ignoring its margins that I set. [The text margin going through the image](https://imgur.com/a/q0Ytk7s). Is there any easy way to center the text between the image and the line below?

Comment: I would recommend setting the parent element that contains the hashtags and "Placeholder" text to display: flex as flexbox allows you to position elements easily vertically. It is a bit difficult to guide you based on just screenshots. If there is a demo of this block you are modifying it would be great if you could send it and I will modify it to look like your screenshot from BetterDiscord